# Circular List Removing Node

Tags: java, data-structures, circular-list

I'm not sure if this is a proper way of creating a remove method for my circular list, also I'm having a problem with getting it to work for a 1 Node list.

```
public void remove() {
    if(first.getNext() == null) {
        first = null;
        first.setNext(null);
    } else {
        Node current = first;
        for(int i = 0; i < getSize() - 1; i++) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        first = first.getNext();
        current.setNext(first);
        size--;
    }
}
```

I have it working properly for lists that are greater than two, but I am not sure if this was the best way to tackle the problem. Does anyone have any suggestions for ways to improve this, as well as getting a one Node list to remove properly? Even though I set the first node to null, and the next Node to null as well, it still returns back my original input.

EDIT: For anyone who looks at this in the future, I just printed out a message saying that you cannot remove the element. As my assignment was quite ambiguous with what to do for it.

Comment: you could add more details or code! whats getSize? if its list total elements, you can directly check getsize()==1. how you retrieve data?

Comment: getSize() returns the size of the circular list, getData() returns the integer that's stored in the Node, getNext() returns the Node which the current one is pointing too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not work. I guess, it does not get to execute the follwoing part at all:

```
    first = null;
    first.setNext(null);
```

The reason i sthat this would raise a NullpointerException. You first set the `first`to null and than try to dereference the `null`.

I will not provide you the exact code (as this is some kind of homework right? ;)), but check this pseudo code from wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list):

```
  function remove(List list, Node node)
    if node.prev == null
      list.firstNode := node.next
    else
      node.prev.next := node.next
    if node.next == null
      list.lastNode := node.prev
    else
      node.next.prev := node.prev
    destroy node
```

Comment: Yeah it's for an exercise, I've been given the code and need to create a remove function which takes in no parameters, and I'm not allowed to change any of the existing code.